# Using MultiSelectListPreference with dynamic data

Tags: android, preferences

Is it possible to use `MultiSelectListPreference` with dynamic data stored in preferences? The data is a list of string dynamically added by the user.
In all examples I saw it must be backed by static names/values defined in `arrays.xml`